# Reference type List<T> with order by

Tags: reference, sql-order-by

I have weird situation, I can't explain, can someone help me to understand it?
As my understanding, List is a reference type, it mean that after we change the list inside function Rating, the list will be changed outside the function. But in real it doesn't change after I sorting. Is there any problem that I misunderstand?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> data = new List<User> 
        { 
            new User { TotalScore = 0 }, 
            new User { TotalScore = 3 }, 
            new User { TotalScore = 4 } 
        };
        Rating(data);
        //List data doesnt order descending by TotalScore
    }

    private static void Rating(List<User> data)
    {
        data = data.OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalScore { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Rating(ref List<User> data), try that

Answer (score 0):

List is a reference type, however you should not confuse this with passing an argument by reference into a function. By default, function arguments in C# are passed by value. You are currently passing the `data` reference by value into `Rating`, so the `data` variable in that function is a copy of the reference in the caller. This allows the function to mutate the same list through the reference, but any assignments will only affect the local variable.

To pass a variable by reference you need to use the `ref` keyword:

```
private static void Rating(ref List<User> data)
{
    data = data.OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList();
}
```

and change the call to:

```
Rating(ref data);
```

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your answering. But I dont think problem come from ref keyword. Because if I change the Rating into this, It will change the data variable in outside.                                      private static void Rating(List<User> data)
            {
                //data = data.OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList();
                data.Add(new User { TotalScore = 4 });
            }

Comment: @user3697101 - Is that not what you want? If you just want to mutate the list in place then you will need to use `List<T>.Sort` since `OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList()` returns a new list.

Comment: Hi Lee, OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList() return a  new list, but then it will assign back to data variable, so it should be changed in outsite without using ref keyword. Because in second sample (data.Add(new User { TotalScore = 4 })), I still don't use ref keyword but it change in outside. So my question is what is the different here, between using OrderByDescending(e => e.TotalScore).ToList() and data.Add(new User { TotalScore = 4 }); One will be changed in outsite, but the other doesnt.

Comment: @user3697101 - My answer explains why you _do_ need to pass by reference here. Your two examples are not equivalent - in the first you are trying to assign to a variable in an outer scope, in the second you are just mutating an object through a copy of a reference.